# How to Get Text from Online File .text

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, push-notification

I'm creating an application with C# that should should download data as text from a file (found online) at this location: http://asap.eb2a.com/a.text.

I need to get the text data only. My code so far:

```
//  this.Hide();
//  notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
WebClient Get= new WebClient();
Uri Line = new Uri("http://asap.eb2a.com/a.text");
AAA:
var text = Get.DownloadData(Line);
// var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\b.txt");
//System.IO.File.Delete(@"D:\Not.text");
label1.Text = text.ToString();
while (text.ToString() == text.ToString())
try
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = (Convert.ToString(text));
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "We Notify You";
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(150);
    BBB:   var text1  = Get.DownloadData(Line);
    //System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\b.txt");
    while(text.ToString()==text1.ToString())
    {
        await Task.Delay(50);
        goto BBB;
    }
    await Task.Delay(50);
    goto AAA; 
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

In order to make sure that the data is not the same I do some loops and I get this in Notify [image: Error With Notification]

Comment: Please, please, please, please don't use [GOTO](https://xkcd.com/292/)! What you are trying to do can be done without labels and goto operators.

Comment: any idea elser ? @pasty

Comment: Why do you need the `Task.Delay(50);`? Why do you need the `while` loop? You can use `DownloadString` (to download the complete string atz once) instead of  `DownloadData`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do - do you want only the text from the response? Is your problem the unwanted HTML code that is shown in the notify message? If so then have a look at the result in the debuger to see why the fetched repsonse in not as the expected. Maybe the web site is containing a message that explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your problem is the HTML text showed in the notify icon text. Probably the web site (asap.eb2a.com...) does not allow unknown agents, so it returns some message to inform you or the `a.text` file contains HTML and JavaScript code. The first problem can be bypassed by adding a [header to the WebClient object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to mask your call as if it is coming from a web browser:

```
Get.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

The loops created using the `goto/label` construct can be replaced by a [System.Timers.Timer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will also simplify your code:

- create the WebClient object to call the uri
- create a variable to preserve the downloaded text
- create a timer object and bind the [Elapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, that is called every `100` milliseconds
- in the timer Elapsed event download the data from the site using the  [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method
- compare the already saved text with the newly downloaded string: if their are different, then show the notify icon

The implementation looks like this:

```
WebClient Get = new WebClient();
// identify your self as a web browser
Get.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
Uri uri = Uri("http://asap.eb2a.com/a.text");
string contentToShow = String.Empty;
// timer for the repetitive task called every nnn milliseconds
const long refreshIntervalInMilliseconds = 100;
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(refreshIntervalInMilliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Fetching data from: {1}", DateTime.Now, uri));
    try
    {           
        var result = Get.DownloadString(uri);
        if (result != contentToShow)
        {
            contentToShow = result;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = contentToShow;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "We Notify You";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(150);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error: {0}", exception.Message));
    }
};
// start the timer
timer.Start();
```